# from pytorch_transformers ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I am running into this error when using pytorch_transformers in Colab environment after installing Anaconda and activating it. I found a similar issue in https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/1705 but it does not work for me. Thanks for your help!

```
!pip install transformers
!pip install simpletransformers
!pip install pytorch-transformers

import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = "/usr/local/bin/python"

import sys!source activate transformers!source activate transformers
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/')

!conda --version
!conda update -n base conda
!conda install -q -y --prefix /usr/local -c conda-forge tqdm
!conda create -n transformers tqdm
!source activate transformers

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import glob
import logging
import os
import random
import json

import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.utils.data import (DataLoader, RandomSampler, SequentialSampler,
                              TensorDataset)
import random
from torch.utils.data.distributed import DistributedSampler
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook, trange

from pytorch_transformers import (WEIGHTS_NAME, BertConfig, BertForSequenceClassification, BertTokenizer,
                                  XLMConfig, XLMForSequenceClassification, XLMTokenizer, 
                                  XLNetConfig, XLNetForSequenceClassification, XLNetTokenizer,
                                  RobertaConfig, RobertaForSequenceClassification, RobertaTokenizer)

from pytorch_transformers import AdamW, WarmupLinearSchedule

from utils import (convert_examples_to_features,
                        output_modes, processors)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

     22 from pytorch_transformers import AdamW, WarmupLinearSchedule
     23 
---> 24 from utils import (convert_examples_to_features,
     25                         output_modes, processors)
     26 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

Comment: It seems you're running on an old version of `transformers`, `convert_examples_to_features` are now `glue_convert_examples_to_features` which you can import directly from `transformers`.

Comment: @Lysandre thanks for the tip! I also need output_modes and processors. Do you know where those moved?

Comment: You can import them as `glue_output_modes` and `glue_processors` directly from `transformers` as well. You can check the [run_glue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/run_glue.py) script for an example.